# TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings

Tags: python

I am getting the following error when running the script below,can anyhelp to identify what the problem is and how to overcome it

```
import subprocess
import sys
import os

def main ():
    to = ''
    ssh_command = ["ssh", "-p", "29418", "review-android.quicinc.com", "gerrit",
                   "query", "--format=JSON", "--current-patch-set",
                   "--commit-message", "--files", ]

    with open('gerrit_output.txt', 'a') as fp:
        with open('caf_gerrits.txt','r') as f :
            for gerrit in f :
                print gerrit
                result = subprocess.check_output(ssh_command + [gerrit, ])
                print result
                fp.write(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

ERROR:-

545804

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 20, in <module>

  File "test.py", line 15, in main

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 537, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings
```

Answer (score 31):

The third element in `ssh_command` is an integer.  It needs to be a string.

e.g:

```
ssh_command = ["ssh", "-p", 29418, ...
#                            ^ problem
```

And the solution is simple, just add some quotes:

```
ssh_command = ["ssh", "-p", "29418", ...
#                           ^Now it's a string.
```

Comment: @user2955256 -- Same Error?  If there is the same error, you should post exactly what we need to *reproduce* the problem.  e.g. post the exact contents of `gerrit`.  If we can't reproduce your problem, then we're really just guessing at what is going wrong.

Comment: its the exact same issue

Comment: Please edit the question to include your updated code and the updated error message.

Comment: My bet is that the `gerrit` variable probably contains a trailing newline (`.strip()` it to get rid of that problem).

Comment: @MaxNoel - I tried that too..still the same problem..am perplexed

Answer (score 3):

First you need to add the quotes around `29418` as mgilson mentioned. Second let's break down what you're trying to run:

```
ssh_command = ["ssh", "-p", 29418, "review-android.company.com", "gerrit",
               "query", "--format", "JSON", "--current-patch-set",
               "--commit-message", "--files", ]
```

That equals

```
ssh -p 29418 review-android.company.com gerrit query --format JSON --current-patch-set --commit-message --files
(then I'm assuming you have filenames in your caf_gerrits.txt file which get appended at the end)
```

One thing that pops out at me is that you may want to say `--format=JSON` in which case your elements in the `ssh_command` array should be combined as `[..., "--format=JSON", ...]`. The other thing you may want to do is `print result` after your `result=` line to help with the debugging.

Answer (score 0):

check all the values that you pass to the subprocess command. One of them isn't a string.

I had the same error
`TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings` for

`p1 = Popen(['aws', 'route53', 'change-resource-record-sets', '--hosted-zone-id', zone, '--change-batch', r53json], stdout=PIPE)`

But as you can see it wasn't the 3rd parameter. The only variable was zone and I found that it was a list. Passing the parameter ass zone.id fixed the issue.

`TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings` has all the clue you need.